# How to use grep to construct a pattern to catch the '\n' in strings

Tags: grep

In Linux, I can use

```
$grep -r " is not exist\!\!"
```

to catch the lines of

```
printf(" %s is not exist!!\n", path);
```

But when I use

```
$grep -r " is not exist\!\!\n"
$grep -r " is not exist\!\!\\n"
```

Nothing returns.

How should I construct the string pattern so that I can exactly catch the '\n' in a string such as in a **printf**?

Comment: Could you please do add more samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then. That will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: You need to use four backslashes: `grep -r " is not exist\!\!\\\\n"`. Both bash and grep interpret backslash as a special character. You pass to bash: "\\\\n". Bash passes to grep: "\\n". Grep internally interprets this regexp as a fixed string consisting of two characters: "\n".

Comment: I tried, 3 backslashes is enough. But 4 backslashes has the same effect. So why you suggest 4? @gudok